# In android, how to set imageview in cardview top left and top right rounded?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-cardview

[click to open image like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrgBy.png)

i put image i want to like this using `cardview`so please kindly reply here.

Comment: What have you achieved until now? You want the `cardview` to be rounded(your cardview is currently having sharp corners) or you just want to create it from beginning. Please tag with @DakshAgrawal when replying.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `card_view:cardCornerRadius`

For eg :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view_inner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="0dp" >
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

> For more references, Please refer this [CardView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView)

Comment: with cardElevation i want to. check image i put as demo like and refere this below link : http://gmariotti.blogspot.com/2014/11/android-5-card-and-images-with-rounded.html

Comment: @RajendraChauhan, can you please post the code which you try, so that i can help you more.

Answer (score -1):

```
**Use code like below and you will achieve it** 


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view_notification"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
        card_view:contentPadding="7dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iconLead"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/logo" />
        </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iconLead1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:src="@drawable/logo1" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iconLead2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/logo2" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iconLead3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:src="@drawable/log3o" />


</LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```